# JS Script being (seemingly) ignored in .jsp (Netbeans)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, netbeans

I'm trying to make a .jsp where, by clicking a button, the page opens a modal dialog with some stuff. I'm also using jQuery. I'm new to this, so, to test if jQuery was working, I first tried a kind of "Hello World" like this:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bibliopdf.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        $("#h01").text("Hello jQuery");
    }

    $(document).ready(myFunction);
</script>
```

And, in the body part, just at the beginning I have a:

```
<h1 id="h01"></h1>
```

Now, if I try running this project on Netbeans, the "Hello jQuery" appears just as expected. Which means jQuery is being recognized just fine.

But the problem begins when I elaborate on things, trying to make a button to open a modal dialog. The function I made then becomes:

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        $("#h01").text("Hello jQuery");

        var diag;
        diag = $("#idNovoDialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 300,
            width: 350,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Adicionar",
                "Cancelar",
            }
        });

        $("#idNovo").button().on( "click", function() {
            diag.dialog("open");
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(myFunction);
</script>
```

And the .jsp now has:

```
<div id="idNovoDialog">
        Some stuff
    </div>
```

And a button:

```
<input type="button" value="NOVO" style="width:180px;" id="idNovo"/>
```

So, if I try running this, it acts as if the script was never there to begin with. Not only does the dialog part not work, but the "Hello jQuery" part also stops working. Since it worked before, I believe there's a mistake somewhere in the javascript code, but I really couldn't find it.

Could anyone tell what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The script tag is outside the head and the body tag. Perhaps try adding it to either?

Comment: Doesn't help. At first I thought it was that too, but the code with only the "Hello jQuery" part had worked even with the tag outside the head and body, so...

Comment: See answer below ... issue was with how you defined the buttons of the dialog - can't define a JSON object with just string array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is how you are defining the `buttons` of the dialog options:

```
        buttons: {
            "Adicionar",
            "Cancelar",
        }
```

Per the JQuery UI docs, when you set it to an object, the keys are the names of the buttons, and the values are the functions called when the buttons are clicked.

```
        buttons: {
            "Adicionar": function() {
                // Action here
            },
            "Cancelar": function() {
                // Action here
            }
        }
```

Working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ynr4b64g/
JQuery UI Buttons Docs: http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-buttons

Comment: This helps, thanks! I'm still intrigued that tozer's code worked on jsfiddle but not on my Netbeans, though... I don't discard the possibility Netbeans is misbehaving, since it gave me headaches other times too. But anyway, thanks again, Jason. :)

Answer (score 0):

Changing your code up a bit I was able to get it working..

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#h01").text("Hello jQuery");
});

$(function () {
    $("#idNovoDialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 300,
        width: 350,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Adicionar": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            "Cancelar": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });
});

$("#idNovo").on("click", function () {
    $("#idNovoDialog").dialog("open");
});
```

working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/fzrgtkdq/

Comment: This works just like I want it to on jsfiddle, but for some odd reason, when I put the exact same code on Netbeans, the Hello jQuery appears, but the button doesn't work... Is it possible that Netbeans (or Tomcat, since I'm also using that) is causing trouble somewhere?

Comment: When you open up your page for testing view the source code and click on the js and css files for your jqeury to make sure they are being linked correctly. I'm not sure but in your post you're missing the 'http:' before the urls and I'm almost wondering if jqueryui is not being loaded..

Comment: Yeah, they are being linked just fine. Tried adding the http anyway, just in case, but still doesn't work on Netbeans. But thanks for your time, anyway!